# Find files which contain string except a couple folders

Tags: linux, bash, search, grep, find

I'm trying find some files and I've written a bash script for it and use it this way - `./findme.sh "before"`, but it doesn't work well. What's the problem?
How I can rewrite it correctly and more beautify?

```
#!/bin/bash
string=$1
clear
find . -name "*.*" ! -path "./node_modules" \
       ! -path "./bower_components" \
       ! -path "./public_lib/bootstrap" \
       ! -path "./public_lib/jquery" \
       ! -path "./public_lib/lib/bootstrap" \
       ! -path "./public_lib/lib/jquery" \
-print | xargs grep -o -r -n -C 3 --color=auto "$string" ./

echo "Search end!"
exit 0
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Search all files in a directory for a pattern?

Comment: I'm trying to:
1. Recursively search for files by content
2. Excluding the specified folders
3. Display found (only matched) in the format "path/file_name:line_number"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can properly use grep for this:

```
#!/bin/bash
grep -rnC 3 --color=auto \
  --exclude-dir={node_modules,bower_components} \
  --exclude-dir=public_lib/{,lib/}{bootstrap,jquery} -- "$1" .
```

Which will search all files recursive for `$1` and show linenumber and three lines above and below the match.

If you want to follow symbolic links you should use `-R` instead of `-r`.

`--exclude-dir={node_modules,bower_components}` uses brace expansions and will expand to:

```
--exclude-dir=node_modules --exclude-dir=bower_components
```

And the more advanced `--exclude-dir=public_lib/{,lib/}{bootstrap,jquery}`, will expand to:

```
--exclude-dir=public_lib/bootstrap --exclude-dir=public_lib/jquery \
--exclude-dir=public_lib/lib/bootstrap --exclude-dir=public_lib/lib/jquery
```

Backslash and newline added for clarification.

Comment: Doesn't work. This I've gotten with my script http://imgur.com/Ga8qJuW (ignore excluded dirs) and this - with yours http://imgur.com/mxJangf

Comment: @ValSaven I omitted the `-o` since it will extract the matches and not show the full line.

Answer (score 0):

Accoding to the find manpage, you'd have to either specify the full filenames that you want not matched, e.g. `! -path "./node_modules/*" ! -path "./node_modules/*/*"` (etc. if it goes deeper) or use prune, e.g. `\( \( -path "./node_modules" -prune \) -o ...`, in that case you'd have to make a big OR separated with -o for each path to be excluded e.g.

```
find . -name "*.*" \(  -path "./node_modules"  -prune \) -o \
       \(  -path "./bower_components" -prune \) -o \
       \(  -path "./public_lib/bootstrap" -prune \) -o \
       \(  -path "./public_lib/jquery" -prune \) -o \
       \(  -path "./public_lib/lib/bootstrap" -prune \) -o \
       \(  -path "./public_lib/lib/jquery" -prune \) -o \
-print | xargs...
```

*Edit* sorry the condition easily messes up as you see...

Comment: Probably simplify as `\( -path ... -o -path .... -o path ... \) -prune -o -name "*.*" -print | xargs ...`, since above is really `-name "*.*" -a \(  -path "./node_modules"  -prune \)`, and `-a` is higher presedence than `-o`.